# How to optimize cursor in a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

I'm having problems with a stored procedure that iterates over a table, it works fine with a few hundred rows however when the table is over the thousands it saturates the memory and crashes.

The procedure should iterate row by row and fill a column with a value which is calculated from another column in the row. I suspect it is the cursor that crashes the procedure and in other questions I've read to use a while loop but I'm no expert in sql and the examples I tried from those answers didn't work.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GenerateNewHashes]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @module BIGINT = 382449983

    IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.telephoneSource WHERE Hash IS NULL)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE hash_cursor CURSOR FOR 
             SELECT a.telephone, a.Hash 
             FROM dbo.telephoneSource AS a

        OPEN hash_cursor 

        FETCH FROM hash_cursor 

        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            UPDATE dbo.telephoneSource 
            SET Hash = CAST(telephone AS BIGINT) % @module 
            WHERE CURRENT OF hash_cursor

            FETCH NEXT FROM hash_cursor
        END

        CLOSE hash_cursor 
        DEALLOCATE hash_cursor 
    END
END
```

Basically the stored procedure is intended to fill a new column called Hash that was added to the existing table, when the script that updates the table ends the new column is filled with NULL values and then this stored procedure is supposed to fill each null value with the operation telephone number (which is a bigint) % module variable (big int as well).

Is there anything besides changing to a while loop that I can do to make it use less memory or just don't crash? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you used a cursor?  If not you can do a loop and do your updates in batches in the loop instead of one by one with a cursor.  Loops are way better way to do something if you can avoid a cursor do so (meaning dont use them).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
WHILE 1=1
BEGIN
    UPDATE TOP (10000) dbo.telephoneSource
    SET Hash = CAST(telephone AS BIGINT)%@module
    WHERE Hash IS NULL;

    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    BEGIN
        BREAK;
    END;
END;
```

This will update `Hash` as long as there are `NULL` values and will exit once there have been no records updated.

Adding a filtered index could be useful as well:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_telephoneSource_Hash_telephone
    ON dbo.telephoneSource (Hash)
    INCLUDE (telephone)
WHERE Hash IS NULL;
```

It will speed up lookups in order to update it. But this might be not needed.

Comment: A much more robust batch solution then that based on min/max ID values (which itself is based on an unstated assumption). Statement terminators included as a bonus. ++

Comment: thank you very much, this way was the only one that worked

Answer (score 0):

Here is example of code to do it in loops from my comment above with out using a cursor, and if you add where your field you are updating IS NOT NULL into the inner loop it wont update ones that were already done (in case you need to restart the process or something.

I didnt include your specific tables in there  but if you need me to I can add it in there.

```
DECLARE @PerBatchCount as int
DECLARE @MAXID as bigint
DECLARE @WorkingOnID as bigint

Set @PerBatchCount = 1000

--Find range of IDs to process using yoru tablename
SELECT @WorkingOnID = MIN(ID), @MAXID = MAX(ID)
FROM YouTableHere WITH (NOLOCK)


WHILE @WorkingOnID <= @MAXID
    BEGIN 
        -- do an update on all the ones that exist in the offer table NOW
        --DO YOUR UPDATE HERE
        -- include this where clause where ID is your PK you are looping through    
        WHERE ID BETWEEN @WorkingOnID AND (@WorkingOnID + @PerBatchCount -1)

    set @WorkingOnID = @WorkingOnID + @PerBatchCount  

END

SET NOCOUNT OFF;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simply add computed column:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.telephoneSource
ADD Hash AS (CAST(telephone AS BIGINT)%382449983) PERSISTED;
```